# Is there any way to merge multiple .cog files into one using python?

Tags: python, gdal, merge, mosaic, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I need to merge several .cog files into one. I have tried using rasterio, rioxarray, gdal, etc but I have not been able to get it to work.

The closest I have been able to get was through this function

```
def unir_archivos_cog(archivos_entrada, archivo_salida):
    try:
        # Crear una lista con los comandos para gdal_translate
        comandos = [
            'gdal_translate',
            '-co', 'COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES',
            'VRT:' + ' '.join(archivos_entrada),
            archivo_salida
        ]

        # Ejecutar el comando
        subprocess.run(comandos, check=True)

        print(f'Archivos unidos con éxito en: {archivo_salida}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ocurrió un error: {str(e)}')
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message saying that the file is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Does anyone know how to fix it, either using gdal or any other library?